# How to update a set of JavaFX2.2 TextFields from a Service?

Tags: service, javafx-2, textfield

I am trying understand how to update a set of textfields in the JavaFX2.2 UI using a Service, but there are no samples nor tips for this in the documentation. Both the Addressbook and Ensemble samples deal with tables. The Service would return an ObservableList of Strings.
How would one do the binding?

textField0 <---> observableList[0]

textField1 <---> observableList[1]

I modified the ServiceSample (Concurrency | Service sample at http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.2/samples/Ensemble/index.html) to have a **ListView of TextFields** but I do not know how to do the binding.
What should I put instead of

```
tableView.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());
```

this line will not even compile:

```
listView.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());
```

modified Concurrency | Service sample at http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.2/samples/Ensemble/index.html

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.Date;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

/**
 * A sample showing use of a Service to retrieve data in a background thread.
 * Selecting the Refresh button restarts the Service.
 *
 * @see javafx.collections.FXCollections
 * @see javafx.concurrent.Service
 * @see javafx.concurrent.Task
 * @see javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator
 * @see javafx.scene.control.TableColumn
 * @see javafx.scene.control.TableView
 */
public class ServiceSample extends Application {

    final GetDailySalesService service = new GetDailySalesService();

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        VBox vbox = new VBox(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(12));
        ListView<TextField> listView = new ListView<TextField>();
        Button button = new Button("Refresh");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                service.restart();
            }
        });
        vbox.getChildren().addAll( listView, button);

        Region veil = new Region();
        veil.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)");
        ProgressIndicator p = new ProgressIndicator();
        p.setMaxSize(150, 150);

        p.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());
        veil.visibleProperty().bind(service.runningProperty());
        p.visibleProperty().bind(service.runningProperty());
        // what to put here ? tableView.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());

        StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        stack.getChildren().addAll(vbox, veil, p);

        root.getChildren().add(stack);
        service.start();
    }

    /**
     * A service for getting the DailySales data. This service exposes an
     * ObservableList for convenience when using the service. This
     * <code>results</code> list is final, though its contents are replaced when
     * a service call successfully concludes.
     */
    public class GetDailySalesService extends Service<ObservableList<String>> {

        /**
         * Create and return the task for fetching the data. Note that this
         * method is called on the background thread (all other code in this
         * application is on the JavaFX Application Thread!).
         *
         * @return A task
         */
        @Override
        protected Task createTask() {
            return new GetDailySalesTask();
        }
    }

    public class GetDailySalesTask extends Task<ObservableList<String>> {       
        @Override protected ObservableList<String> call() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                updateProgress(i, 500);
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }
            ObservableList<String> sales = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            sales.add(new String("A1"));
            sales.add(new String("A2"));
            return sales;
        }
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer demonstrates using a bind to update a set of JavaFX 2 TextFields from a Service.  The basis of the answer is the original example code posted in your question.  The updates work because the type of the values for the ListView (Strings) now match the type of the values returned from the service.

To your original code, make the following modifications:

Change:

```
ListView<TextField> listView = new ListView<TextField>();
```

To:

```
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>();
```

Change:

```
// what to put here ? tableView.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());
```

To:

```
listView.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());
```

Now the listView will be updated based on the service results (to demonstrate the changes, you can add a some random data in the service task rather than using fixed data).

So now you have a ListView whose data gets updated based on the values of the list coming in.  But you want a list of TextFields, rather than a list of static labels.  To get TextFields into the ListView, you need to create your own cell factory.

Here is an update to your original example.  The update provides a couple of cell factories to handle the TextField creation.  The InstantEditingCell creates TextFields for all items.  The ClickableEditingCell creates cells when you click on the items (the code for that class was copied from the EditingCell in the [JavaFX TableView sample documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm)).

```
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.*;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.util.Callback;

/**
 * A sample showing use of a Service to retrieve data in a background thread.
 * Selecting the Refresh button restarts the Service.
 *
 * @see javafx.collections.FXCollections
 * @see javafx.concurrent.Service
 * @see javafx.concurrent.Task
 * @see javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator
 * @see javafx.scene.control.TableColumn
 * @see javafx.scene.control.TableView
 */
public class ServiceSample extends Application {

    final GetDailySalesService service = new GetDailySalesService();
    final Random random = new Random();

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        VBox vbox = new VBox(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(12));
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.setEditable(true);
        Button button = new Button("Refresh");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                service.restart();
            }
        });
        listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
            @Override public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                return new InstantEditingCell();
            }
        });
        listView.setPrefHeight(200);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll( listView, button);

        Region veil = new Region();
        veil.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)");
        ProgressIndicator p = new ProgressIndicator();
        p.setMaxSize(150, 150);

        p.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());
        veil.visibleProperty().bind(service.runningProperty());
        p.visibleProperty().bind(service.runningProperty());
        listView.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());

        StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        stack.getChildren().addAll(vbox, veil, p);

        root.getChildren().add(stack);
        service.start();
    }

    /**
     * A service for getting the DailySales data. This service exposes an
     * ObservableList for convenience when using the service. This
     * <code>results</code> list is final, though its contents are replaced when
     * a service call successfully concludes.
     */
    public class GetDailySalesService extends Service<ObservableList<String>> {

        /**
         * Create and return the task for fetching the data. Note that this
         * method is called on the background thread (all other code in this
         * application is on the JavaFX Application Thread!).
         *
         * @return A task
         */
        @Override
        protected Task createTask() {
            return new GetDailySalesTask();
        }
    }

    public class GetDailySalesTask extends Task<ObservableList<String>> {       
        @Override protected ObservableList<String> call() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                updateProgress(i, 500);
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }
            ObservableList<String> sales = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            sales.add("A1: " + random.nextInt());
            sales.add("A2: " + random.nextInt());
            return sales;
        }
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    class InstantEditingCell extends ListCell<String> {
        @Override public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                final TextField textField = new TextField(getString());
                textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()* 2);
                textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
                    @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> value, Boolean wasFocused, Boolean isFocused) {
                        if (!isFocused) {
                            commitEdit(textField.getText());
                        }
                    }
                });
                setGraphic(textField);
            }
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }
    }

    class ClickableEditingCell extends ListCell<String> {

        private TextField textField;

        public ClickableEditingCell() {
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                super.startEdit();
                createTextField();
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
                textField.selectAll();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();

            setText((String) getItem());
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(getString());
                    }
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(textField);
                } else {
                    setText(getString());
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        }

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()* 2);
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
                @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, 
                    Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
                        if (!arg2) {
                            commitEdit(textField.getText());
                        }
                }
            });
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }
    }

}
```

Because TextFields are editable objects rather than static objects, you probably also want to work out some way to commit your edits back to wherever the original data came from.

Sample program output:

[image: Text Field List]

Comment: thanks for your input. when compiling even though I am using jdk1.7, I get compile error, "diamond operator is not supported in this release. use source 1.7" at  line 42      ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();

Comment: You must have the `-source` level for your [compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) set to something lower than 1.7, effectively disabling Java 7 compilation features.  Diamond operator is just a convenience anyway, you can use `ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>();` instead.

Comment: I accepted your answer but couldn't help wondering if my solution was simpler.

Comment: Yes - I see your updated solution makes use of VBox values, which are generally simpler to work with than the virtualized ListViews. VBoxes lack some functionality that ListViews have such as like default styling, virtual cell apis, inbuilt scrolling support, etc.  It just depends on the application and context which container and solution is the more applicable one to use.

Answer (score 0):

This sorta worked, but there is no 'automatic' way to bind a list of TextFields to the output of a Service.

```
import java.lang.String;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.WorkerStateEvent;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

/**
 * A sample showing use of a Service to retrieve data in a background thread.
 * Selecting the Refresh button restarts the Service.
 *
 * @see javafx.collections.FXCollections
 * @see javafx.concurrent.Service
 * @see javafx.concurrent.Task
 * @see javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator
 * @see javafx.scene.control.TableColumn
 * @see javafx.scene.control.TableView
 */
public class ServiceSample extends Application {

    final GetDailySalesService service = new GetDailySalesService();

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        final VBox vbox = new VBox(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(12));

        Button button = new Button("Refresh");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                service.restart();
            }
        });
        TextField tf1, tf2, tf3;
        tf1 = new TextField();
        tf1.setId("0");
        tf2 = new TextField();
        tf2.setId("1");
        tf3 = new TextField();
        tf3.setId("2");        
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(tf1,tf2,tf3,button);

        Region veil = new Region();
        veil.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)");
        ProgressIndicator p = new ProgressIndicator();
        p.setMaxSize(150, 150);

        p.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());
        veil.visibleProperty().bind(service.runningProperty());
        p.visibleProperty().bind(service.runningProperty()); 
        StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        stack.getChildren().addAll(vbox, veil, p);

        root.getChildren().add(stack);
            service.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                System.out.println("done:" + t.getSource().getValue());
                List list = service.valueProperty().getValue();
                String[] sa = (String[]) list.toArray(new String[0]);
                for(int i=0; i<sa.length;i++) {
                    TextField tf = (TextField) vbox.lookup("#"+i);
                    tf.setText(sa[i]);
                }
            }
        });
        service.start();
    }

    /**
     * A service for getting the DailySales data. This service exposes an
     * ObservableList for convenience when using the service. This
     * <code>results</code> list is final, though its contents are replaced when
     * a service call successfully concludes.
     */
    public class GetDailySalesService extends Service<ObservableList<String>> {
        /**
         * Create and return the task for fetching the data. Note that this
         * method is called on the background thread (all other code in this
         * application is on the JavaFX Application Thread!).
         *
         * @return A task
         */
        @Override
        protected Task createTask() {
            return new GetDailySalesTask();
        }
    }

    public class GetDailySalesTask extends Task<ObservableList<String>> {       
        @Override protected ObservableList<String> call() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                updateProgress(i, 500);
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }
            ObservableList<String> sales = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            sales.add(new String("A1 " + System.currentTimeMillis()));
            sales.add(new String("A2 " + System.currentTimeMillis()));
            sales.add(new String("A3 " + System.currentTimeMillis()));
            return sales;
        }
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```